# My discord.js bot seems to be running multiple instances at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So what I'm trying to do is a simple bot that can detect commands. I made a '!test' command that does a few things (replies to the message, deletes it and then deletes the answer later, but also logs the command in a channel).

It seems to work fairly well, however it spams the answer and executes the series of actions multiple times : http://prntscr.com/nkgj8m (more and more every time when I restart the bot).

I tried to delete the app and recreate it, and it worked well : the message showed up only once, until I restarted the bot.

I made a '!stop' command that destroys the client, but it doesn't work as intended : the bot is disconnected (says "stop" in my console), but almost instantly reconnects on my server (and I don't see the logs in my local console anymore).

It seems to be a little "random" though about the count of messages. Some bot messages are also sometimes not deleted at all, and are not logged as well.

Here's my code (I never really did anything in js before so I might misuse some things, or some things might be not optimal, sorry about that - I did some research and most things I think are good, or decent at least).

```js
// Require libs
require('dotenv').config()
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Get discord client
var client = new Discord.Client();
initialize();

// --------------------------------------------------
//      INITIALIZE
// --------------------------------------------------

function initialize() {
    // On ready
    client.on("ready", function() {
        console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}! Yup, this is the default message.`);
    });

    // On message
    client.on("message", function(input) {
        // server message
        if (input.guild.available) {
            // get the message content
            var command = input.content.toLowerCase();
            // stop command
            if (command.startsWith("!stop")) {
                client.destroy();
                console.log("Stopped");
            }
            // test command
            else if (command.startsWith("!test")) {
                input.reply(`This is my answer to your test !`)
                    .then(function(output) {
                        consumeCommand(input, output, 5000);
                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
            }
        }
    });

    // login bot client
    client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
}

// --------------------------------------------------
//      CONSULE AND LOG COMMANDS
// --------------------------------------------------

// Log the output of a command, delete the input message and delete the output soon
// input, message, the user message
// output, string, is the bot output
// outputTimeout, int, is the time we should wait until deleting the bot's output
function consumeCommand(input, output, outputTimeout) {
    // delete input
    input.delete(0)
        .then(function() {
            console.log(`Deleted message ${input.content}`)
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    // log
    var logChannel = input.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'guiguibot-commands');
    if (logChannel != null) {
        logCommand(input, output, logChannel);
    } else {
        console.log("Trying to log bot command but there's no guiguibot-commands channel");
    }
    // delete output later if not null
    if (output != null && outputTimeout != null) {
    }
}

// Log the output of a command
// input, message, the user message
// msg, message, the user message
// output, string, is the bot output
function logCommand(input, output, logChannel) {
    // has output
    if (output != null) {
        logChannel.send(`@${input.author.username} sent a command`, {
          embed: {
            fields: [
              {
                name: ":keyboard: Input :",
                value: `\`${input.content}\``
              },
              {
                name: ":robot: Output :",
                value: `\`${output.content}\``
              }
            ]
          }
        })
            .then(() => console.log('Logged user action'))
            .catch(console.error);
    }
    // no ouput
    else {
        logChannel.send(`@${input.author.id} sent a command (no output was found)`, {
          embed: {
            fields: [
              {
                name: ":keyboard: Input :",
                value: `\`${input.content}\``
              }
            ]
          }
        })
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Logged user action')
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

So, my question would be : how do I make sure that there's only one instance of my code running ? (if I deducted the problem correctly). Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Heroku or another service to host the bot, or running node from your computer?

Comment: @slothiful I run 'npm run start' (where start runs 'node index.js') on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by simply hosting it on Heroku like @slothiful suggested ! I guess my script was just restarted again and again and the connections to the discord server were multiplied ? Idk exactly. Fact is now it works fine, only one instance is processing my commands.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to make an initialize() method, just do it like this:

```
// Require libs
require('dotenv').config()
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Get discord client
var client = new Discord.Client();

// On ready
client.on("ready", function() {
    console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}! Yup, this is the default message.');
});

// On message
client.on("message", function(input) {
    // server message
    if (input.guild.available) {
        // get the message content
        var command = input.content.toLowerCase();
        // stop command
        if (command.startsWith("!stop")) {
            client.destroy();
            console.log("Stopped");
        }
        // test command
        else if (command.startsWith("!test")) {
            input.reply('This is my answer to your test !')
                .then(function(output) {
                    consumeCommand(input, output, 5000);
                })
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
});

// --- CONSOLE AND LOG COMMANDs go here ---

// login bot client
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Yeah I know, it's just me there wanting to use a function, as I'm more used to Java it disturbs me x) Does it actually affect performance or something ?

Comment: @GuillaumeVDN i am just not used to do it your way and i thought that this is your problem.. but if it still executes the onready and  onmessage it should be fine i guess